# Fetch the user along with a list of databases to which that user has access

Tags: sql, sql-server

Providing screenshot here - `test_user` has access to `master` and `new_database`:

[image: screenshot: test_user has access to master and new_database]

The requirement is that I should fetch username and database name (database name should be in the format of `username@databasename` - for example: `test_user@master`)

I tried using this query, but it is fetching all the database names, not only the ones to which the user has access:

```
SELECT 
    dp.name AS login_name,
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT(dp.name, '@', d.name), ', ') AS dbuser_list
FROM 
    sys.database_principals dp
JOIN 
    sys.databases d ON d.database_id > 0  
GROUP BY 
    dp.name;
```

Comment: `database_principals` is database specific; you'll need to run the query against *every* database. Also `database_principals.name` doesn't give you the `LOGIN`'s name, it gives you the `USER`'s name; these are different things. The `LOGIN`'s name will be in `server_principals`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT ''???'' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS DATABASE_NAME, sp.name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS LOGIN_NAME, dp.name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS SQL_USER_NAME 
FROM   [???].sys.database_principals AS dp
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp
          ON dp.sid = sp.sid ';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + REPLACE(@QUERY, '???', name)  + ' UNION ALL '
FROM   sys.databases;
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10)
SET @SQL = N'WITH T AS (' + @SQL + ') SELECT SQL_USER_NAME + COALESCE('' ('' + LOGIN_NAME + '')'', '''') + '' : '' + STRING_AGG(DATABASE_NAME, '', '') AS SQL_USER
FROM T 
GROUP BY SQL_USER_NAME, LOGIN_NAME 
ORDER BY 1;'
EXEC (@SQL);
```

This will give you the attendee result... The name of SQL User will appear with the login inside parenthesis if needed...

Comment: So many issues with this code: variable coalescing, no `QUOTENAME`, the `ORDER BY 1`, not using `max`

Answer (score 2):

The other answer has some major issues.

- Variable coalescing is an anti-pattern and can cause wrong results.
- Needs `QUOTENAME` to correctly quote.
- `ORDER BY 1` is confusing at best.
- Dynamic SQL needs to be `max`.

Here is a better version:

```sql
DECLARE @union nvarchar(max);
SELECT @union =
  STRING_AGG(
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), '
    SELECT STRING_AGG(dp.name + ''@'' + ' + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + ', '', '') AS dbuser_list
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.database_principals AS dp
    WHERE dp.sid = sp.sid
', '
    UNION ALL
')
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.database_id > 4; -- not system


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT sp.name, dp.*
FROM sys.server_principals AS sp
CROSS APPLY (
' + @union + '
) dp;
';

PRINT @sql; --your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```